# UINavigationBar is off center?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

So I recently set up an app with a navigation bar except it's refusing to stay in the middle of the screen. The title is moved slightly to the right and the right-most button is hidden off screen. I've tried everything from resizing, to deleting it and re adding it, to cleaning, etc... and nothing works. Any idea why this might be? :\

This is what it looks like when run on the simulator vs the Storyboard
[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like it has any constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The title is centered, but the `UINavigationBar` is 600px wide.  Your screen is not that wide.  You need to add layout constraints that resize the toolbar appropriately for the containing view.

You need to add layout constraints.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+DRAG from the `UINavigationBar` to its parent view (in the left hierarchical tree-view tool window):

[image]

And add the following constraints (hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while selecting):

- Leading Space to Container
- Trailing Space to Container
- Top Space to Top Layout Guide

Comment: Thanks for the help! I don't remember ever having to do this in previous versions of xCode so I take it this must be new? :(

Comment: AutoLayout is relatively new.  I think more recent versions of Xcode have actually turned it on by default when you create new storyboards.